# Convert a special type of timestamp to date in Python

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe with timestamp as following:

```
2021-12-21 04:27:00.052000046
```

I want to convert it to the following to do some time series analysis

```
2021-12-21 04:27:00
```

What I have tried is as following. That being said, convert 'pandas.core.series.Series' to string and then split.

```
 dt['Time (s)'].to_string().split(".")[0]
```

and I got the following

```
0      2022-12-21 04:27:00  
...
```

How can I get rid of the `0` in front? Thank you.

Comment: Would `dt['Time (s)'] = dt['Time (s)'].dt.floor('S')` solve your problem ?

Comment: @Timeless Wonderful solution. Could you please explain the solution a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. By using [`floor('S')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), we're rounding the time to the nearest second and thus, the fractional seconds disappear.